# Why can't I redirect index page with apache .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have a site with just a handful of pages, and I am trying to do a 301 redirect of everything.  Everything works except the index file.  It doesn't matter if I write it out as `http://example.com/index.html` or `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com`, the index file won't show a redirect.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 / https://example2.com/
Redirect 301 /index.html https://example2.com/
Redirect 301 /services.html https://example2.com/services/
Redirect 301 /contact-us.html https://example2.com/contact/
```

It might help that when someone puts `https://example.com/`, it gets changed to `https://example.com` without the "/".  I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Thanks

Comment: Redirect permanent / https://secure.example.com/

Comment: I tried that first.  Did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `Redirect` to be effective within an `.htaccess` file, you must allow the `FileInfo` override in your virtual host definition in your `httpd.conf` configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName   www.example.com
  ServerAlias  example.com

  ... blah blah

  <Directory "/">
    ...
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    ...
  </Directory>

  ... blah blah

</VirtualHost>
```

Add the `AllowOverride FileInfo` line to your configuration, restart the Apache server, and try again.

Comment: That line is in there.  If it weren't, the other redirects wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your full VirtualHost def?  If you can provide more than just a narrow keyhole view of your config, perhaps someone can spot the problem.